# Most efficient htaccess url redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm looking for the most efficient way to redirect incoming urls to the https: version of our site.  What we have in place works (see below), I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do it, and to minimize the number of redirects.

Redirecting should cover the following cases:

```
(Domain level)
http://www.example.com - > https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/dir -> https://www.example.com/dir
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://example.com/dir -> https://www.example.com/dir
www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
www.example.com/dir -> https://www.example.com/dir
example.com -> https://www.example.com
example.com/dir -> https://www.example.com/dir

(Subdomains)
http://subdomain.example.com -> https://www.example.com/subdomain
subdomain.example.com -> https://www.example.com/subdomain
```

Here's what we have in our htaccess file:

```
# Rewrite subdomains to folders, add www if not present
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite anything not previously caught
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By your rules you forced both `main-domain` and `sub-domain` into `https` but only `non-www` of `main-domain` into `wwww` so , to get it work for both do this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test